# Android + KOTLIN: find folders and store their names as string array

Tags: android, kotlin, directory

I have a PHP script which has the ability to automatically find folders and send their names to the client as string so that they can be used in `innerHTML` buttons. I'd like to do EXACTLY the same thing in my Android app with Android Studio and Kotlin, but I failed to find any specific way to do that.

Here's the PHP code that fetches all folder names and stores them as an array:

```
$_SESSION['$folders'] =[] #initiates array
$_SESSION['$folders'] = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir'); #finds subfolders in the root folder and stores their names
```

However, both folders and PHP script are in the same directory, so no further path string treatment is required other than `array_filter` and its elimination arguments `glob('*')` and `is_dir` as you can see in the code above, and THAT is the "magic" I'm looking for with Kotlin.

Couldn't send pictures because it seems I don't have enough reputation here.

Comment: Tidied formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you should strictly specify the path of the folder you want to view.
Start point could be `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` - the primary shared/external storage directory.

Then you could get list of files with method `dir.listFiles()`. If you need to filter it somehow (for example have only directories) you could add a **FileFilter**: `dir.listFiles(FileFilter { it.isDirectory })`

Another important thing is that you have to have a permission for reading external storange. Thus you should add to your **Manifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Starting from Android 6.0 you should additionally ask for this permission:

```
Fragment.requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), READ_STORAGE_RC)
```

And handle results in **Fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult** method.

---

I created example of how it could be used together.
You need to create activity and add a Fragment inside:
**DirListFragment**

```
class DirListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val adapter by lazy { DirListAdapter { dir = it } }
    private var dir: File by observable(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) { _, _, _ -> onNewParent() }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dir_list, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        checkPermissionReadStorage(requireActivity())
        list.adapter = adapter
        up.setOnClickListener { dir = dir.parentFile }
        onNewParent()
    }

    private fun onNewParent() {
        parent.text = dir.absolutePath
        adapter.items = dir.listFiles(FileFilter { it.isDirectory })?.toList() ?: emptyList()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == READ_STORAGE_RC && permissionGranted(requireActivity())) onNewParent()
    }

    private fun checkPermissionReadStorage(activity: Activity) {
        if (!permissionGranted(activity)) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), READ_STORAGE_RC)
        }
    }

    private fun permissionGranted(activity: Activity) =
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

    private companion object {
        const val READ_STORAGE_RC = 123
    }
}
```

**DirListAdapter**

```
class DirListAdapter(private val clickListener: (file: File) -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DirListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var items by Delegates.observable(listOf<File>()) { _, _, _ -> notifyDataSetChanged() }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ViewHolder(parent)

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.caption.text = items[position].name
        holder.caption.setOnClickListener { clickListener(items[position]) }
    }

    class ViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        (LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false)) {

        val caption: TextView = itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)
    }
}
```

**fragment_dir_list.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:text="UP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/up"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            tools:text="Parent dir"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_below="@id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help to understand the basis.

Comment: Hi, Dima S. Thank you SO much for your time and help! During my attempt to get the folder names (which will eventually be used to complete the path to their files), I came to the realization that assets were what I was looking for because I wanted my folders to contain sub folders and everything should be part of the app folder, so my solution was to create an asset folder and call my sub folder as follows: val rootpath = resources.assets.list(pic_folders) // pic_folder is the directory containing the subfolders whose names I need stored as arrays to be shown in buttons. Thanks again!